# Is there a way to run code up to a "certain point", quit, and then start running again without an interruption

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, google-apps-script, google-apps

My script gets data from a CSV file and then exports it to a Google Sheet. the CSV file consists of a 2D array and has 9000 + rows. My current script runs fine but give an error of

> Incorrect Range Width, was 1 but should be 5

This error only occurs if I process the whole CSV file, whereas if I separate the file into chunks it processes fine without any errors using the same code. Therefore the error is with the amount of rows. I use a loop feature it times out.

I was wondering if there is a way to run the code to process 2000 rows quit and then start again without any interruptions. I have been stuck on this error for several weeks and really need help. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
Function getCSV() {
var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B2lVvlNIDosoajRRMUwySVBPNVE');        //reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved 
var date= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy");
var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('L661_BOM-CAD_07-01-16.csv'); 
// latest  report file
var ss =   SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V8YG8lyNZiTllEPHENcnabYRLDPCK6mHGUyAyNhW0Is').getSheet    s()[0]; // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be  updated  with new report data Sheet will be opened server side. 

ss.getName() == "Sheet1"
if ( fi.hasNext()) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports    folder
var file = fi.next();
//file.setName('L661_BOM-CAD_'+ date +'(EXPORTED)'+'.csv');
var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var csvData = CSVToArray(csv);
Logger.log('csvData[0].length: ' + csvData[0].length + ' csvData.length:'  + csvData.length);
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();

ss.getRange(lastrow +  1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues((csvData));
}

//adds the last modified date to the first row
if( ss.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r= ss.getRange('A1');
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 5);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
var date = new Date();
var date= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy");
nextCell.setValue(date); //enters the date in F1 in dd/mm/yyyy format
 };
 };
};

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){

strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ';');

var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
        // Delimiters.
        "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

        // Quoted fields.
        "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

        // Standard fields.
        "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
    );


var arrData = [[]];


var arrMatches = null;

while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
        strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
        strMatchedDelimiter !== strDelimiter
        ){

        // Since we have reached a new row of data,
        // add an empty row to our data array.
        arrData.push( [] );

    }

    var strMatchedValue;

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

        // We found a quoted value. When we capture
        // this value, unescape any double quotes.
        strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
            new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
            "\""
            );

    } else {

        // We found a non-quoted value.
        strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    Logger.log('arrData[0].length: ' + arrData[0].length);
}

// Return the parsed data.
return( arrData );
}
```

Comment: Can't you add a counter and an if-condition if it reaches 2000 to print something to the console. Then use the browser developer tools to set a breakpoint to the print statement. Because of the if-condition, it will pause the program after 2000 iterations.

Comment: I am very new to google script or javascript so i would not know. I have been researching on this but getting no where. Can you please explain a little bit more. Google script for dummies type of thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your delimiter is a semicolon.

Here's how to import and write to the currently open sheet

```
function getcsv(){

  // get the data from drive
  var csvString = DriveApp
    .getFileById('0B92ExLh4POiZTHFDUThmaHE2d2s1LVpvbWhyNjJaOE1MejBZ')
    .getBlob()
    .getDataAsString();

  // convert to array of arrays
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ';');

  // write to sheet
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1,1,csvData.length, csvData[0].length)
    .setValues(csvData);


}
```

Comment: THAT WORKED, but the file ID will change everytime it is imported so i tried to use the file name and date option and it came up with the getblob error

Comment: You'll need to use getFilesbyName to open the file if you dont know its id. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=en#getFilesByName(String)

Comment: i have tried this but no luck: `function getcsv(){
  var date= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy");
  // get the data from drive
  
  var csvString = DriveApp
    .getFileByName("L661_BOM-CAD_"+date+".csv")
    .getBlob()
    .getDataAsString();` i get the following error message: **TypeError: Cannot find function getFileByName in object Drive**

Comment: The method name is getFilesByName and it returns a file iterator, since there can be more than one file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I can'f find the loop that goes over the rows in your code, but essentially you could do something like that (you need a `var rowcount = 0` the value of which you increase with every row):

```
if (rowcount == 2000) {
    console.log("found row 2000");
}
```

Then set a breakpoint on the `console.log()`.

- [Firefox developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)
- [Setting breakpoints in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint)

Comment: You can also use `debugger` keyword.

Comment: I am really sorry but i do not understand

Comment: It's OK, but without concrete questions, I don't know how to explain.

Comment: Basically i want the code to get for example 2000 rows from the CSV file input it into the google sheet, and then start again from where it left off, do this in chunks of 2000 or so until it is at the end of the CSV file. This is because the code cannot handle the amount of data in the CSV file and it gives an incorrect width error message. However if i process the data in chunks it runs through the script fine. Hopefully this makes it a little bit easier to understand

Comment: No, I perfectly understand. But you have to find out how to use the debugger for my solution, I can't help you there. I gave you two links.